# How to leverage the Neural Engine on Apple Silicon/M1 processors as a developer?

Tags: machine-learning, deep-learning, neural-network, apple-m1, apple-silicon

I am struggling to find an answer for this on SO, Google, or Apple's Developer Documentation.

Does Apple provide a APIs for any languages that allow developers to leverage the Neural Engine of the new M1 chips on macOS?

Searching Apple's Developer Documentation brings up a lot of functions in the Metal Performance Shaders library, which seems to use GPU acceleration.

Searching SO with the tags [apple-m1](/questions/tagged/apple-m1) or [apple-silicon](/questions/tagged/apple-silicon) and the keyword "neural" gives nothing useful.

Searching r/AppleDevelopers for "neural" turns up nothing.

I assume there has to be some information about how to develop using the neural cores. Are these cores only available to Apple developers and commercial partners?

Answer (score 1):

Apple doesn't provide direct public API to Neural Engine.
Some frameworks might be accelerated via Neural Engine:

1. Accelerate
2. CoreML
3. BNNS
4. MLCompute

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately not. You can only use the Neural Engine through Core ML at the moment.
There currently is no public framework for programming the ANE. There are several private, undocumented frameworks but obviously we cannot use them as Apple rejects apps that use private frameworks.
(Perhaps in the future Apple will provide a public version of AppleNeuralEngine.framework)
But. Check this https://github.com/hollance/neural-engine/tree/master/docs
and this https://github.com/antgroup-arclab/ANETools
You can learn how ANE works and what to do with it.